# Conver list of numbers to floating point in Python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x

in pyDLM I create

```
data = [0]*100 + [3]*100.
```

`data` then is a list. How do I make all 200 items in data floating point numbers?

Comment: Why don't you start with `0.0` and `3.0` instead?

Comment: `data = [float(x) for x in data]` @jonrsharpe maybe it's just an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of ints and want a list of floats, you can use various techniques.

For instance:

```
[float(n) for n in my_list]
```

Or:

```
map(float, my_list) # python2

list(map(float, my_list)) # python3
```

Comment: `map` won't return a `list` in python 3.

Comment: Indeed. I edited my answer accordingly.